# Android MediaCodec MixVBP: unknown header 12 is parsed

Tags: android, h.264, android-mediacodec

I'm using the Android MediaCodec api in C++ to decode streamed video (`video/avc`) and audio (`audio/mp4a-latm`). I'm using a Nexus Player device on Android M.

I've found that the first couple of seconds of playback show a black screen, and during that time I get the following error in log cat:

`MixVBP: unknown header 12 is parsed.`

From a little googling I think the message comes from [this source](https://github.com/thuutin/hardware_intel_common_libmix/blob/master/mixvbp/vbp_manager/secvideo/baytrail/vbp_h264secure_parser.c#L1698).

It's trying to parse the NAL header, and doesn't recognise NAL unit type 12 (filler data).

Has anyone experienced this problem before? Is the only way to fix this to modify the stream and strip out the filler data NAL units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my black screen issue wasn't anything to do with this warning.

Removing the Filler Data NAL Units did get rid of this warning however.